# How can I downgrade core?

Tags: composer, 9

I have Drupal version 9.1 but the [Get JWT on Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/getjwtonlogin) module is not available for Drupal 9.x, so I need to downgrade to the latest version of Drupal 8.x. Is it possible to do that through Composer?

Comment: With some forcing you'd probably be able to get the files updated, but I doubt you'll find an easy way to downgrade a D9 database to D8

Comment: @leymannx seems like there is not v9 patch for that module yet. He would have to create one.

Comment: @NoSssweat – Seems there is https://www.drupal.org/project/getjwtonlogin/issues/3140655. And maybe that's all what's needed.

Comment: The easiest route here is to update that module sonit is compatible. Far less work.

Comment: @NoSssweat, this was what I needed. The jwtonlogin is working in drupal 9.x.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @leymannx is the one who deserves all the credit.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  You are right.  I was confused.  All credit deserves @leymannx.